# node_modules developing dependency package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hyperlink, node-modules, package.json

I am studying an aplication that has some dependencies. I want to make some changes on one dependency locally.

I tryed to make a symbolic link inside the main application's node_modules direct to the dependency folder, where I have the folders with compiled code (es and lib) using this command `ln -s dependency_folder main_app/node_modules/dependecy`.

It doesn't work and raises an error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Is this a right way to develop a dependency package, or I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that there is no problem to link to a dependency package. What happened here is that the project source files are out of date. Compiled dependencies are up to date on NPM, on git the sources are outdated.

i will leave this message just for the records.